# Exception while publishing, due to CCSID mismatch

Tags: messaging, ibm-mq, websphere-8

Developed a bar file using WMB 6.

Deployed in WMB 8 environment.

Have a broker "MSBK01"(WMB 8) with queue manager "MSBK01".The **CCSID** of the queue manager is **819**.

Have another broker "MSBK01"(WMB 8) with queue manager "MSBK02". The **CCSID** of this queue manager is **1208**.

I am **posting a message with CCSID 1208**(also setting the MQMD.CCSID=1208 in code as well).

The code is not throwing any parsing exception. My **final node is the publication** node.
I am getting an exception for "unconvertible character".

After running a trace I found that the exception is coming after the message reaches the publication node(my final node).

But my code is working fine for the MSBK02 which has the queue manager with CCSID 1208.

Now I replaced the publication node in my flow with MQOutput node and I got the correct output in both brokers(CCSID 819 and CCSID 1208).
So, its the Publication node creating the problem.

**My question is how can I make sure that the publication node doesn't try to convert my message.**

I tried to finalise my message, but no success.

Help required. Also, the flow is working fine in WMB 6, Queue manager with CCSID 850.

Below is final part of trace.

```
2012-12-13 16:02:53.256804     6239   UserTrace   BIP2537I: Node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.SF_IP1_PST_1_SAP_P104_CDF_TOPIC.ESQL_PROCESSING': Executing statement   ''PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'out' FINALIZE DEFAULT DELETE NONE;'' at ('com.ms.sap.SF_IP1_PST_1_SAP_P104_CDF_TOPIC_ESQL_PROCESSING.Main', '87.6'). 
 2012-12-13 16:02:53.258176     6239   UserTrace   BIP4016I: Message propagated to terminal ''out'' of node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.SF_IP1_PST_1_SAP_P104_CDF_TOPIC.ESQL_PROCESSING' with the following message trees: 'InputLocalEnvironment, OutputRoot, InputExceptionList'. 
2012-12-13 16:02:53.258276     6239   UserTrace   BIP7080I: Node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.Publication.ComIbmPSService': The Publication Node with Subscription Point '''' has received a message of type 'Publish'. 
                                       The Publication Node with Subscription Point '''' has started processing a message. 
                                       No user action required. 
2012-12-13 16:02:53.261320     6239   UserTrace   BIP2231E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.SF_Broker_Input_Basic.Queue_Name_Promoted'. 
                                       The message broker detected an error whilst processing a message in node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.SF_Broker_Input_Basic.Queue_Name_Promoted'. The message has been augmented with an exception list and has been propagated to the node's failure terminal for further processing. 
                                       See the following messages for details of the error. 
2012-12-13 16:02:53.261340     6239   RecoverableException  BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.SF_AUDIT_VALIDATE_CME.MAIN'. 
                                       The message broker detected an error whilst processing a message in node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.SF_AUDIT_VALIDATE_CME.MAIN'. An exception has been thrown to cut short the processing of the message. 
                                       See the following messages for details of the error. 
2012-12-13 16:02:53.261348     6239   RecoverableException  BIP2488E:  ('.SF_AUDIT_VALIDATE_CME_MAIN.Main', '109.5') Error detected whilst executing the SQL statement ''PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'out3' FINALIZE DEFAULT DELETE DEFAULT;''. 
                                       The message broker detected an error whilst executing the given statement. An exception has been thrown to cut short the SQL program. 
                                       See the following messages for details of the error. 
2012-12-13 16:02:53.261380     6239   RecoverableException  BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.SF_IP1_PST_1_SAP_P104_CDF_TOPIC.ESQL_PROCESSING'. 
                                       The message broker detected an error whilst processing a message in node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.SF_IP1_PST_1_SAP_P104_CDF_TOPIC.ESQL_PROCESSING'. An exception has been thrown to cut short the processing of the message. 
                                       See the following messages for details of the error. 
2012-12-13 16:02:53.261388     6239   RecoverableException  BIP2488E:  ('com.ms.sap.SF_IP1_PST_1_SAP_P104_CDF_TOPIC_ESQL_PROCESSING.Main', '87.6') Error detected whilst executing the SQL statement ''PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'out' FINALIZE DEFAULT DELETE NONE;''. 
                                       The message broker detected an error whilst executing the given statement. An exception has been thrown to cut short the SQL program. 
                                       See the following messages for details of the error. 
2012-12-13 16:02:53.261396     6239   ParserException  BIP5010E: XML Writing Errors have occurred. 
                                       Errors have occurred during writing of XML. 
                                       Review further error messages for an indication to the cause of the errors. 
2012-12-13 16:02:53.261412     6239   RecoverableException  BIP2136E: Source character ''0393'' in field ''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'' cannot be converted from Unicode to codepage '819'. 
                                       The source character is an invalid code point within the given codepage. 
                                       Correct the application or message flow that generated the message to ensure that all data within the message can be represented in the target codepage. 
2012-12-13 16:02:53.262060     6239   UserTrace   BIP4163I: Message propagated to the first terminal of the FlowOrder node 'com.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104.SF_Broker_Input_Basic.SF_Handle_Exception.FlowOrder'. 
                                       The FlowOrder node has received a message and has propagated it to the output terminal called first. Once the processing of the message down the first terminal has finished, the message will be propagated to the second terminal. 
                                       No user action required.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publication node tries to convert the message to the queue manager's CCSID.
Even though I set the MQMD's CCSID to 1208, publication node tries to convert the message to the queue manager's CCSID.

But, it seems publication node looks for the MQRFH2 for the CCSID instead of MQMD, as my message type was MQRFH2.

When I set the MQRFH2 CCSID as below, **I got no exception**, and the message got published.

```
 SET OutputRoot.MQRFH2.(MQRFH2.Field)NameValueCCSID = 1208;
 SET OutputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId = 1208;
```